# Checking for several possible values in the 'name' field in an azure policy

Tags: azure-policy

I have an azure policy for that enforces a naming convention for app services of 'kind' api. I got it mostly working. The policy should allow for the creation of app services that follow this format (??-*-api-dev, ??-*-api-stage, ??-*-api-prod). Everything was working until I put in the last bit to check for the -environment part. Policy is now allowing resource creation no matter what is put in the name field.

Below is the json of my definition:

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "match": "Microsoft.Web/sites"
        },
        {
          "field": "kind",
          "match": "api"
        },
        {
          "not": {
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "value": "[if(greaterOrEquals(length(split(field('name'), '-')), 4), split(field('name'), '-')[0], 'length of name incorrect')]",
                "match": "??"
              },
              {
                "value": "[if(greaterOrEquals(length(split(field('name'), '-')), 4), split(field('name'), '-')[1], 'length of name incorrect')]",
                "match": "*"
              },
              {
                "value": "[if(greaterOrEquals(length(split(field('name'), '-')), 4), split(field('name'), '-')[2], 'length of name incorrect')]",
                "equals": "api"
              },
              {
                "value": "[if(greaterOrEquals(length(split(field('name'), '-')), 4), split(field('name'), '-')[3], 'length of name incorrect')]",
                "notIn": "[parameters('validEnvironments')]"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "validEnvironments": {
      "type": "Array",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Allowed Environments",
        "description": "The list of environments that can be specified during resource deployment."
      },
      "allowedValues": [
        "dev",
        "stage",
        "prod"
      ],
      "defaultValue": [
        "dev",
        "stage",
        "prod"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. I just needed to do allOf instead of anyOf. Put the final code below. Hopefully this can help out anyone trying to enforce semi-complex naming conventions using Azure Policies.

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "match": "Microsoft.Web/sites"
        },
        {
          "field": "kind",
          "match": "api"
        },
        {
          "not": {
            "allOf": [
              {
                "value": "[if(equals(length(split(field('name'), '-')), 4), split(field('name'), '-')[0], 'length of name incorrect')]",
                "match": "??"
              },
              {
                "value": "[if(equals(length(split(field('name'), '-')), 4), split(field('name'), '-')[1], 'length of name incorrect')]",
                "like": "*"
              },
              {
                "value": "[if(equals(length(split(field('name'), '-')), 4), split(field('name'), '-')[2], 'length of name incorrect')]",
                "equals": "api"
              },
              {
                "value": "[if(greaterOrEquals(length(split(field('name'), '-')), 4), split(field('name'), '-')[3], 'length of name incorrect')]",
                "in": "[parameters('validEnvironments')]"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "validEnvironments": {
      "type": "Array",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Allowed Environments",
        "description": "The list of environments that can be specified during resource deployment."
      },
      "allowedValues": [
        "dev",
        "stage",
        "prod"
      ],
      "defaultValue": [
        "dev",
        "stage",
        "prod"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```